# WordPress htaccess redirect | NextGEN Gallery Pro - Lightbox

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, nextgen-gallery

I am using NextGEN Gallery Pro - Lightbox on my WordPress site which should redirect first-url to second-url automatically, but somehow it doesn't work and generates a blank page without any redirect when I visit the first url. I am thinking to add a manual htaccess rewrite rule to make this redirect possible.

How can I add htaccess rewrite rule to redirect

```
mywordpress_domain.com/nextgen-share/121212/8989/full?uri=/landscape-photography/
```

to

```
mywordpress_domain.com/landscape-photography/#gallery/121212/8989
```

This is the rewrite rule I've tried so far.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(nextgen-share)/([\w\d\-]/([\w\d\-]+)/(full?uri=)?$/([\w\d\-]+)/ $3/#gallery/$1/$2 [L,R=301]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: URL rewriting is an already broadly discussed, and well documented topic. You should really show a bit more effort here, than just go “how can I …?”

Comment: @04FS I've already tried several htaccess rewrite rules before posting this question but no joy.

Comment: Then _show_ what you tried, so that we can see _that_ you tried.

Comment: @04FS I've tried few but the last one I've tried is added in the main question.

Comment: RewriteRule matches against the _path_ component of the requested URL only. If you want to do any checking or matching on the _query string_ contents - then you need to use a `RewriteCond` to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following rewrite rule finally fixed the issue.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^uri=(/[^&]+)
RewriteRule ^nextgen-share/(\d+/\d+)/full$ %1#gallery/$1 [QSD,NE,R,L]
```